# Dimension of a subspace of a function space

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

> The dimension of the real vector space $V=\{(-1,1)\to\mathbb{R}\mid f \text{ is infinitely differentiable on (-1,1) and} f^{(n)}(0)=0 \; \text{for all} \; n \ge0 \}$

---

There are four options:

(a) $0$

(b) $1$

(c) greater but finite

(d) infinite

Answer says option (d), but I can't solve it at all as I don't even know where to begin. I just want some hints to get started on this problem.

**NOTE:** This a question from TIFR GS2021

Comment: Hint: Start by considering the function $f(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$, with $f(0) := 0$. What can you say about this function and its derivatives at $0$? Can you use this to construct other functions which satisfy the conditions of the set?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: If $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$,$f^{'}(x)=\frac{2f(x)}{x^3}$ and $f^{'}(0)$ causes $\frac{0}{0}$ problem.

Comment: @abhijeetVats can you elaborate a little bit more?I still can't solve it.

Comment: What are you stuck on specifically?

Comment: I can't find the elements of V.